# Draw the "{} CODE GOLF & coding challenges" logo!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, geometry

Wow, time really flies! It's already been one year since the [debut of the Code Golf Stack Exchange site design](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live). Let's celebrate this milestone with a code golf challenge... to imitate the site logo!

Golf a program that outputs a graphic of a medal enclosed in curly braces `{}`, along with two lines of text containing `CODE GOLF` and `& coding challenges`.

The medal graphic `{}` should consist of the following:

- **The medallion:** A solid-filled circle with radius `r`, surrounded by a concentric ring of the same color with an outer radius between `1.5r` and `1.6r` and a thickness between `0.2r` and `0.3r`.
- **The ribbon:** A solid-filled, horizontally symmetrical hexagon with height between `3r` and `4r` and side lengths ranging from `1.8r` to `2.4r`, placed directly above the medallion and sharing its vertical axis of symmetry.

  - A "y"-shaped cutout within the hexagon (masked out or solid-filled with the background color). This is defined by a horizontally centered, solid, downward-pointing acute isosceles triangle, with the right side extended by a line segment of thickness up to `0.3r` that intersects with the bottom left vertex of the hexagon. (The left and right sides should be co-linear with the top left and top right vertices of the hexagon, respectively.)
- **A pair of curly braces** `{` and `}` with a height between `6r` and `7r`, such that the imaginary horizontal axis that joins the "spikes" `{——}` falls below the apex of the cut-out isosceles triangle and above the medallion's outer ring.

The text output should consist of the string `CODE GOLF` above the string `& coding challenges`, with the horizontal spans of `&` and `s` falling within those of `C` and `F` respectively. You can achieve this any way you like, including, but not limited to:

- Rendering text within the image, to the right of the `{}`.
- Rendering text in a separate image, window, or GUI element.
- Printing to standard output/standard error.

To justify the text, you may add spaces uniformly between the letters and words such that the letter spacing to word spacing ratio is no more than 2/3, e.g:

```
C  O  D  E   G  O  L  F
&   coding   challenges
```

Ensure all shapes and glyphs in your output are solid-filled and non-overlapping. Optionally, color your medal `#F7CC46` gold and `#0061BA` blue (and `#004E96` blue?) for some bonus internet points!

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the less bytes, the better. Be sure to include a screenshot in your answer!

---

For reference, the [official SVG logo](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/Img/logo.svg) is as follows:

```css
html { background: #2b2520 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="126" viewBox="0 0 200 42" fill="none">
    <path d="M74.053 22.38c-1.561 0-2.976-.332-4.245-.994a7.756 7.756 0 0 1-2.977-2.785c-.714-1.195-1.072-2.54-1.072-4.037 0-1.497.358-2.836 1.072-4.016a7.546 7.546 0 0 1 2.977-2.785c1.269-.676 2.691-1.015 4.267-1.015 1.327 0 2.523.23 3.588.691a7.184 7.184 0 0 1 2.714 1.987L78.1 11.498c-1.036-1.18-2.32-1.77-3.851-1.77-.949 0-1.795.208-2.539.626a4.405 4.405 0 0 0-1.75 1.705c-.409.735-.613 1.57-.613 2.505 0 .935.204 1.77.613 2.504a4.556 4.556 0 0 0 1.75 1.727c.744.403 1.59.605 2.539.605 1.531 0 2.815-.598 3.851-1.792l2.276 2.072a7.085 7.085 0 0 1-2.714 2.008c-1.08.46-2.283.691-3.61.691zM89.869 22.38c-1.59 0-3.028-.339-4.311-1.015-1.27-.677-2.269-1.605-2.998-2.786-.715-1.194-1.073-2.533-1.073-4.015 0-1.483.358-2.814 1.073-3.994a7.663 7.663 0 0 1 2.998-2.807c1.283-.676 2.72-1.015 4.31-1.015 1.59 0 3.02.339 4.29 1.015a7.664 7.664 0 0 1 2.998 2.807c.729 1.18 1.094 2.511 1.094 3.994 0 1.482-.365 2.82-1.094 4.015-.73 1.18-1.73 2.109-2.998 2.785-1.27.677-2.7 1.015-4.29 1.015zm0-2.98c.904 0 1.721-.202 2.45-.605a4.444 4.444 0 0 0 1.707-1.727c.423-.734.635-1.569.635-2.504 0-.936-.212-1.77-.635-2.505a4.296 4.296 0 0 0-1.706-1.705c-.73-.418-1.547-.626-2.451-.626-.905 0-1.722.208-2.451.626a4.445 4.445 0 0 0-1.729 1.705c-.408.735-.613 1.57-.613 2.505 0 .935.205 1.77.613 2.504a4.6 4.6 0 0 0 1.729 1.727c.73.403 1.546.605 2.45.605zM100.914 7.007h6.959c1.663 0 3.129.317 4.398.95 1.284.62 2.276 1.497 2.976 2.634.715 1.137 1.072 2.462 1.072 3.973 0 1.511-.357 2.835-1.072 3.972-.7 1.137-1.692 2.022-2.976 2.656-1.269.619-2.735.928-4.398.928h-6.959V7.007zm6.784 12.242c1.531 0 2.75-.418 3.654-1.252.919-.85 1.379-1.994 1.379-3.433 0-1.44-.46-2.576-1.379-3.411-.904-.85-2.123-1.274-3.654-1.274h-3.239v9.37h3.239zM130.853 19.314v2.806h-11.86V7.007h11.576v2.807h-8.053v3.282h7.112v2.72h-7.112v3.498h8.337zM150.222 14.326h3.239v6.132c-.832.619-1.795 1.094-2.889 1.425a11.349 11.349 0 0 1-3.304.496c-1.59 0-3.02-.33-4.289-.993-1.269-.676-2.269-1.605-2.998-2.785-.715-1.195-1.072-2.54-1.072-4.037 0-1.497.357-2.836 1.072-4.016.729-1.194 1.736-2.123 3.02-2.785 1.283-.676 2.728-1.015 4.332-1.015 1.343 0 2.561.223 3.655.67a7.24 7.24 0 0 1 2.757 1.943l-2.276 2.072c-1.094-1.137-2.414-1.705-3.961-1.705-.977 0-1.845.201-2.604.604a4.37 4.37 0 0 0-1.772 1.706c-.423.734-.635 1.576-.635 2.526 0 .935.212 1.77.635 2.504a4.557 4.557 0 0 0 1.751 1.727c.758.403 1.619.605 2.582.605 1.021 0 1.94-.216 2.757-.648v-4.426zM164.172 22.38c-1.59 0-3.027-.339-4.311-1.015-1.269-.677-2.269-1.605-2.998-2.786-.715-1.194-1.072-2.533-1.072-4.015 0-1.483.357-2.814 1.072-3.994.729-1.195 1.729-2.13 2.998-2.807 1.284-.676 2.721-1.015 4.311-1.015 1.59 0 3.02.339 4.289 1.015a7.669 7.669 0 0 1 2.998 2.807c.729 1.18 1.094 2.511 1.094 3.994 0 1.482-.365 2.82-1.094 4.015-.73 1.18-1.729 2.109-2.998 2.785-1.269.677-2.699 1.015-4.289 1.015zm0-2.98c.904 0 1.721-.202 2.451-.605a4.45 4.45 0 0 0 1.707-1.727c.423-.734.634-1.569.634-2.504 0-.936-.211-1.77-.634-2.505a4.303 4.303 0 0 0-1.707-1.705c-.73-.418-1.547-.626-2.451-.626-.905 0-1.722.208-2.451.626a4.448 4.448 0 0 0-1.729 1.705c-.408.735-.612 1.57-.612 2.505 0 .935.204 1.77.612 2.504.423.734 1 1.31 1.729 1.727.729.403 1.546.605 2.451.605zM175.217 7.007h3.545V19.27h7.681v2.85h-11.226V7.007zM191.969 9.814v3.994h7.09v2.807h-7.09v5.505h-3.545V7.007H200v2.807h-8.031zM68.163 33.798c.865 0 1.564-.313 2.132-.788.557.382 1.102.649 1.635.788l.343-1.089c-.367-.104-.77-.312-1.208-.602.521-.787.9-1.678 1.161-2.628h-1.255c-.178.764-.45 1.424-.806 1.968a9.46 9.46 0 0 1-1.646-1.713c.781-.59 1.575-1.204 1.575-2.177 0-.96-.628-1.609-1.682-1.609-1.101 0-1.812.845-1.812 1.887 0 .51.19 1.1.51 1.714-.711.498-1.35 1.111-1.35 2.118 0 1.193.911 2.13 2.403 2.13zm-.426-5.974c0-.58.273-.973.687-.973.45 0 .604.313.604.718 0 .567-.438.972-.995 1.355-.19-.383-.296-.753-.296-1.1zm.592 4.943c-.722 0-1.267-.474-1.267-1.18 0-.452.249-.823.592-1.158a10.731 10.731 0 0 0 1.753 1.898c-.331.278-.699.44-1.078.44zM83.658 33.798c.83 0 1.682-.29 2.357-.857l-.569-.857c-.45.336-.994.625-1.658.625-1.148 0-1.93-.752-1.93-1.887 0-1.146.805-1.898 1.966-1.898.521 0 .983.185 1.433.544l.651-.834c-.485-.451-1.22-.799-2.155-.799-1.777 0-3.305 1.088-3.305 2.987 0 1.887 1.386 2.976 3.21 2.976zM90.239 33.798c1.528 0 2.925-1.089 2.925-2.976 0-1.898-1.397-2.987-2.925-2.987-1.528 0-2.926 1.088-2.926 2.987 0 1.887 1.398 2.976 2.926 2.976zm0-1.089c-.948 0-1.516-.752-1.516-1.887 0-1.146.568-1.898 1.516-1.898.947 0 1.516.752 1.516 1.898 0 1.135-.569 1.887-1.516 1.887zM96.902 33.798c.652 0 1.303-.36 1.753-.8h.036l.106.66h1.126v-8.173h-1.374v2.06l.07.962h-.035c-.45-.429-.936-.672-1.599-.672-1.326 0-2.57 1.135-2.57 2.987 0 1.876.995 2.976 2.487 2.976zm.332-1.1c-.888 0-1.41-.66-1.41-1.887 0-1.193.676-1.876 1.481-1.876.426 0 .829.139 1.244.521v2.559c-.403.463-.83.683-1.315.683zM104.407 33.659h1.362v-5.685h-3.885v1.054h2.523v4.63zm.58-6.727c.557 0 .971-.347.971-.891 0-.533-.414-.903-.971-.903-.557 0-.971.37-.971.903 0 .544.414.891.971.891zM108.962 33.659h1.374V29.78c.533-.532.924-.799 1.492-.799.794 0 1.09.417 1.09 1.332v3.346h1.374v-3.52c0-1.47-.616-2.304-1.954-2.304-.889 0-1.552.452-2.097.996h-.047l-.107-.857h-1.125v5.685zM118.48 36.171c2.049 0 3.352-.891 3.352-2.014 0-.996-.782-1.39-2.286-1.39h-1.184c-.723 0-1.102-.162-1.102-.532 0-.232.119-.394.355-.533.308.104.628.162.889.162 1.303 0 2.333-.671 2.333-1.933 0-.37-.178-.718-.379-.938h1.338v-1.019h-2.38a2.792 2.792 0 0 0-.912-.139c-1.279 0-2.393.741-2.393 2.05 0 .67.332 1.18.746 1.47v.046c-.426.278-.698.695-.698 1.065 0 .475.284.764.592.95v.046c-.604.324-.924.74-.924 1.192 0 1.02 1.054 1.517 2.653 1.517zm.024-5.152c-.604 0-1.102-.417-1.102-1.135 0-.694.498-1.123 1.102-1.123.604 0 1.101.429 1.101 1.123 0 .718-.497 1.135-1.101 1.135zm.142 4.272c-1.078 0-1.682-.3-1.682-.81 0-.267.154-.51.569-.741.236.058.509.08.888.08h.924c.781 0 1.172.117 1.172.556 0 .487-.734.915-1.871.915zM133.371 33.798a3.69 3.69 0 0 0 2.357-.857l-.569-.857c-.45.336-.995.625-1.658.625-1.149 0-1.931-.752-1.931-1.887 0-1.146.806-1.898 1.966-1.898.522 0 .983.185 1.434.544l.651-.834c-.486-.451-1.22-.799-2.156-.799-1.776 0-3.304 1.088-3.304 2.987 0 1.887 1.386 2.976 3.21 2.976zM137.369 33.659h1.374V29.78c.533-.532.924-.799 1.492-.799.794 0 1.09.417 1.09 1.332v3.346h1.374v-3.52c0-1.47-.616-2.304-1.954-2.304-.889 0-1.54.452-2.049.973h-.036l.083-1.216v-2.107h-1.374v8.174zM146.283 33.798c.782 0 1.564-.382 2.179-.846h.036l.107.707h1.113v-3.37c0-1.586-.888-2.454-2.499-2.454-.995 0-1.954.382-2.653.787l.497.892c.604-.324 1.256-.602 1.907-.602.948 0 1.338.475 1.386 1.111-2.866.197-4.015.834-4.015 2.107 0 .996.805 1.668 1.942 1.668zm.415-1.042c-.581 0-1.043-.22-1.043-.73 0-.613.616-1.03 2.701-1.17v1.205c-.533.417-1.078.695-1.658.695zM155.351 33.798c.675 0 1.078-.116 1.646-.325l-.319-.984c-.368.15-.687.22-.995.22-.581 0-1.043-.29-1.043-1.053v-6.171h-3.197v1.053h1.835v5.048c0 1.401.723 2.212 2.073 2.212zM162.453 33.798c.675 0 1.078-.116 1.646-.325l-.32-.984c-.367.15-.687.22-.995.22-.58 0-1.042-.29-1.042-1.053v-6.171h-3.198v1.053h1.836v5.048c0 1.401.723 2.212 2.073 2.212zM168.714 33.798c.852 0 1.658-.278 2.274-.672l-.462-.833c-.521.289-1.019.474-1.635.474-1.077 0-1.847-.51-2.001-1.563h4.275c.024-.15.06-.405.06-.671 0-1.575-.96-2.698-2.689-2.698-1.563 0-3.008 1.123-3.008 2.976 0 1.887 1.409 2.987 3.186 2.987zm-.142-4.932c.829 0 1.35.463 1.445 1.389h-3.092c.178-.915.841-1.39 1.647-1.39zM172.878 33.659h1.374V29.78c.533-.532.924-.799 1.492-.799.794 0 1.09.417 1.09 1.332v3.346h1.374v-3.52c0-1.47-.616-2.304-1.954-2.304-.889 0-1.552.452-2.097.996h-.047l-.107-.857h-1.125v5.685zM182.396 36.171c2.049 0 3.352-.891 3.352-2.014 0-.996-.782-1.39-2.286-1.39h-1.184c-.723 0-1.102-.162-1.102-.532 0-.232.119-.394.356-.533.307.104.627.162.888.162 1.303 0 2.333-.671 2.333-1.933 0-.37-.178-.718-.379-.938h1.338v-1.019h-2.38a2.792 2.792 0 0 0-.912-.139c-1.279 0-2.393.741-2.393 2.05 0 .67.332 1.18.746 1.47v.046c-.426.278-.698.695-.698 1.065 0 .475.284.764.592.95v.046c-.604.324-.924.74-.924 1.192 0 1.02 1.054 1.517 2.653 1.517zm.024-5.152c-.604 0-1.102-.417-1.102-1.135 0-.694.498-1.123 1.102-1.123.604 0 1.101.429 1.101 1.123 0 .718-.497 1.135-1.101 1.135zm.142 4.272c-1.078 0-1.682-.3-1.682-.81 0-.267.154-.51.569-.741.236.058.509.08.888.08h.924c.781 0 1.172.117 1.172.556 0 .487-.734.915-1.871.915zM190.019 33.798c.853 0 1.658-.278 2.274-.672l-.462-.833c-.521.289-1.018.474-1.634.474-1.078 0-1.848-.51-2.002-1.563h4.276a4.52 4.52 0 0 0 .059-.671c0-1.575-.959-2.698-2.689-2.698-1.563 0-3.008 1.123-3.008 2.976 0 1.887 1.409 2.987 3.186 2.987zm-.142-4.932c.829 0 1.35.463 1.445 1.389h-3.091c.177-.915.841-1.39 1.646-1.39zM196.801 33.798c1.765 0 2.724-.788 2.724-1.76 0-.903-.485-1.39-2.345-1.795-1.078-.231-1.516-.37-1.516-.775 0-.348.308-.626 1.078-.626.687 0 1.35.209 1.919.568l.627-.822c-.592-.382-1.468-.753-2.428-.753-1.634 0-2.558.706-2.558 1.702 0 .857.699 1.401 2.25 1.714 1.351.277 1.611.486 1.611.856 0 .382-.379.683-1.184.683a4.373 4.373 0 0 1-2.44-.717l-.592.845c.722.474 1.764.88 2.854.88zM45.057 36.394c.872 0 1.575-.043 2.109-.128.562-.084.998-.24 1.307-.466.309-.226.52-.538.632-.934.14-.367.211-.848.211-1.442 0-1.16-.028-2.277-.084-3.352a68.576 68.576 0 0 1-.085-3.564c0-1.612.324-2.771.97-3.479.635-.721 1.69-1.212 3.163-1.47a.101.101 0 0 0 .084-.1.101.101 0 0 0-.084-.099c-1.474-.258-2.528-.734-3.163-1.428-.646-.735-.97-1.909-.97-3.521 0-1.273.029-2.46.085-3.564.056-1.103.084-2.22.084-3.352 0-.594-.07-1.074-.21-1.442a1.69 1.69 0 0 0-.633-.933c-.31-.227-.745-.382-1.307-.467-.534-.085-1.237-.127-2.109-.127h-.074a1.655 1.655 0 0 1 0-3.31h1.592c2.699 0 4.68.439 5.946 1.316 1.265.848 1.897 2.418 1.897 4.709 0 .735-.028 1.414-.084 2.036a17.36 17.36 0 0 1-.169 1.74 310.46 310.46 0 0 0-.169 1.655 36.891 36.891 0 0 0-.042 1.824c0 .367.085.735.253 1.103.169.368.478.707.928 1.018.45.283 1.04.523 1.77.721.316.07.665.13 1.048.175 1.008.121 1.82.932 1.82 1.947 0 1.014-.813 1.822-1.818 1.96-.384.053-.733.121-1.05.203-.73.17-1.32.41-1.77.722-.45.283-.759.608-.928.976a2.627 2.627 0 0 0-.253 1.102c0 .68.014 1.302.042 1.867.057.538.113 1.09.17 1.655.084.537.14 1.103.168 1.697.056.594.084 1.273.084 2.036 0 2.291-.632 3.861-1.897 4.71-1.265.877-3.247 1.315-5.946 1.315h-1.592a1.655 1.655 0 0 1 0-3.31h.074zM14.716 36.394c-.871 0-1.574-.043-2.108-.128-.563-.084-.998-.24-1.308-.466a1.69 1.69 0 0 1-.632-.934c-.14-.367-.21-.848-.21-1.442 0-1.16.027-2.277.084-3.352.056-1.075.084-2.262.084-3.564 0-1.612-.323-2.771-.97-3.479-.635-.721-1.689-1.212-3.163-1.47a.101.101 0 0 1-.084-.1c0-.048.036-.09.084-.099 1.474-.258 2.528-.734 3.163-1.428.647-.735.97-1.909.97-3.521 0-1.273-.028-2.46-.084-3.564a65.75 65.75 0 0 1-.085-3.352c0-.594.07-1.074.211-1.442a1.69 1.69 0 0 1 .633-.933c.309-.227.745-.382 1.307-.467.534-.085 1.236-.127 2.108-.127h.074a1.655 1.655 0 1 0 0-3.31h-1.592c-2.699 0-4.68.439-5.945 1.316C5.988 5.38 5.355 6.95 5.355 9.24c0 .735.028 1.414.084 2.036.029.594.085 1.174.17 1.74.055.537.112 1.089.168 1.655.028.565.042 1.173.042 1.824 0 .367-.084.735-.253 1.103-.169.368-.478.707-.928 1.018-.45.283-1.04.523-1.77.721-.316.07-.665.13-1.048.175C.812 19.634 0 20.445 0 21.46c0 1.014.813 1.822 1.818 1.96.384.053.734.121 1.05.203.73.17 1.32.41 1.77.722.45.283.76.608.928.976.169.367.253.735.253 1.102 0 .68-.014 1.302-.042 1.867-.056.538-.113 1.09-.169 1.655-.084.537-.14 1.103-.169 1.697a21.84 21.84 0 0 0-.084 2.036c0 2.291.633 3.861 1.898 4.71 1.265.877 3.246 1.315 5.945 1.315h1.592a1.655 1.655 0 1 0 0-3.31h-.074z" fill="#fff"/>
    <path fill="#004E96" d="M23.74.772h11.663v4.597H23.74z"/>
    <path d="M35.423.772l4.991 7.225a3 3 0 0 1 .078 3.293l-6.313 10.123h-6.437L35.422.772z" fill="#0061BA"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M29.581 41.228a9.194 9.194 0 1 0 0-18.39 9.194 9.194 0 1 0 0 18.39zm0-16.866a7.671 7.671 0 1 0 0 15.343 7.671 7.671 0 0 0 0-15.343zm-5.901 7.671a5.902 5.902 0 1 1 11.803 0 5.902 5.902 0 0 1-11.803 0z" fill="#F7CC46"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18.748 7.997L23.74.772l4.93 13.249-2.767 7.392h-.919L18.671 11.29a3 3 0 0 1 .077-3.293zm8.994 13.416h3.678l-1.834-4.928-1.844 4.928z" fill="#0061BA"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hmm ... have we not had this before? Or was the one I'm thinking of [tag:ascii-art]? Or maybe it was for our old icon?

Comment: @Shaggy I posted an ascii-art of the new logo in the [Secret Santa's Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17823/58563) a while back. But I don't think it was either used.

Comment: An image with the relevant measurements marked could perhaps be useful as an easier reference than the description.

Comment: Note: the official SVG logo you provided does not conform to your own specifications.

Answer (score 9):

## SVG, 259 bytes

```html
<svg viewBox=-30,-29,200,40><text x=-26 font-size=32>{ }</text><text x=25 y=-9>CODE GOLF</text><text x=29 font-size=9>& coding challenges</text><path fill=blue d=M-4.5-24h9l4,8-4,8h-8l6-12h-5l2,4-4,8-4-8 /><g fill=gold><circle r=6.8 /><circle r=5 stroke=#fff>
```

Also including a screenshot, since this is um.. not exactly best practises and will probably not look right in all browsers.

[image: rendered]

Comment: On my computer `}` shows behind ``

Comment: You can reduce it a little bit more by removing the rest of the commas before negative values, as well as the space in `d= M...`

Comment: You just removed the medallion. Not that it matters anyway, since this is already invalid.

Comment: @Makonede What part do you consider invalid?

Comment: Your answer does not meet the specifications, but more importantly, the `}` shows behind the ``.

Comment: @Makonede Can you point out what part of the specification this violates? Also, per the usual site guidelines, a solution needs only work in one implementation of a language. ``}`` rendering behind the medallion in some browsers is not a problem as long as it works in at least one.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys You're clearly using something to modify the font on your end, I can already tell that in the screenshot you don't have the default font for rendering SVG enabled. It's not about the implementation. And, for one, the medallion doesn't fit the rule of the outer radius being 1.5-1.6 times the inner radius. Also, `CODE GOLF` is too wide, it extends beyond the `&` and `s`.

Comment: @Makonede This is perfectly fine. The & and the s are meant to fit within the span of the F and C.

Comment: @Ausername Good point. Editing that out - **EDIT:** it's been 5 minutes :/

Comment: @Makonede The rendering with the brackets is probably because different system fonts have different default spacings.

Comment: @Ausername Ok. Still doesn't address the specs though.

Comment: Looks like the stroke should have been on the last circle instead. Within the ranges now.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys [You still need to fix the ribbon](https://i.imgur.com/hErNuZp.png).

Comment: @Makonede The specification says "co-linear with the top left and top right vertices of the hexagon", not that those lines must also be the diagonals of the hexagon.

Comment: OK, cool <filler></filler>

Comment: @Makonede I appreciate your attention to detail! Perhaps you'd like to edit out/rewrite your suggestions on the other submissions regarding the horizontal span requirement?

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>123</s> 115 bytes

```
„P122žw•·54†u%í[Ç¤õìEEÖÇćÃKõ&Ê»¦1ćÊ₂à<äć°S£ŸǝzMçqõR^ùµTÄYšαÄâ[¬Å%J#›-J(%í/ûÜN₅≠ÝmÁ∞j!i_´ÿÓÙ7žŠλ•bÀðT×…ƒËÿŠˆu…&Âïªï»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ac8AMP9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAxMjLFvnfigKLCtzU04oCgdSXDrVvDh8Kkw7XDrEVFw5bDh8SHw4NLw7Umw4rCu8KmMcSHw4rigoLDoDzDpMSHwrBTwqPFuMedek3Dp3HDtVJew7nCtVTDhFnFoc6xw4TDolvCrMOFJUoj4oC6LUooJcOtL8O7w5xO4oKF4omgw51tw4HiiJ5qIWlfwrTDv8OTw5k3xb7FoM674oCiYsOAw7BUw5figKbGksOLw7/FoMuGdeKApibDgsOvwqrDr8K7//8) Beats all other answers. Technically, there is only [one other valid answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224066/94066). All other answers don't meet the specifications. Outputs as a plain PBM, and outputs the text after it.

## Output (enlarged)

[image: CGCC symbol]

Actual output size is 22x32.

---

```
„P122žw•...•bÀðT×…...u…...»  # trimmed program
„P1                          # push literal
   22                        # push literal
     žw                      # push 32
       •...•                 # push 166945169634011025567565467884298025990186958890541902453598900323554121322972765574841330722535555954069208033251875962777321153953373288109249110692417567618626198556352935215968754836351913816090583315808287...
            b                # in binary...
             À               # shifted left 1 character
                 …...        # push "codeÿ golf"...
                             # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
               T             # 10...
              ð              # space...
                ×            # s...
                     u       # in uppercase
                      …...   # push "& coding challenges"
                          »  # join stack by newlines
                             # implicit output
```

`ðT×` can also be `9çº` to slightly increase the distance between `CODE` and `GOLF`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ac8AMP9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAxMjLFvnfigKLCtzU04oCgdSXDrVvDh8Kkw7XDrEVFw5bDh8SHw4NLw7Umw4rCu8KmMcSHw4rigoLDoDzDpMSHwrBTwqPFuMedek3Dp3HDtVJew7nCtVTDhFnFoc6xw4TDolvCrMOFJUoj4oC6LUooJcOtL8O7w5xO4oKF4omgw51tw4HiiJ5qIWlfwrTDv8OTw5k3xb7FoM674oCiYsOAOcOnwrrigKbGksOLw7/FoMuGdeKApibDgsOvwqrDr8K7//8)

Comment: This is invalid, you need the text.

Comment: @Ausername This outputs the text after the PBM. The challenge specifically states outputting the text to STDOUT is allowed.

Comment: Do "the horizontal spans of & and s falling within those of C and F respectively"? If not, this is invalid

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes, you can see that the `C` lines up wih the `&` and the `F` lines up with the `s`.

Answer (score 5):

## [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), 432 bytes

Code (compressed version):

```postscript
<</L{lineto}/F{closepath fill}/S{setrgbcolor}/t{translate}/N{newpath}/H/Helvetica/M{moveto}/T{M selectfont show}/C{N 0 360 arc F}>> begin 15 15 scale ({  }) H 7.2 0 2 T (CODE GOLF) H 3.6 9 4 T (& coding challenges) H 2.35 9 1 T 4.2 2.4 t .94 .8 .27 S 0 0 1.5 C 1 1 1 S 0 0 1.25 C .94 .8 .27 S 0 0 1 C 0 3 t 0 .31 .59 S N 1.55 0 M 6{60 rotate 1.55 0 L}repeat F 1 1 1 S N -.7 -1.35 M -.05 0 L -.45 .9 L .45 .9 L -.5 -1.35 L F showpage
```

Code (uncompressed version):

```postscript
% some short-named procedures for later use
<<
  /L {lineto}
  /F {closepath fill}
  /S {setrgbcolor}
  /t {translate}
  /N {newpath}
  /H /Helvetica
  /M {moveto}
  /T {  % text fontname fontsize x y --> ---
    M selectfont show
  }
  /C {  % x y radius --> ---
    N 0 360 arc F
  }
>> begin

15 15 scale

% Draw the texts
({  }) H 7.2 0 2 T
(CODE GOLF) H 3.6 9 4 T
(& coding challenges) H 2.35 9 1 T

% Draw the medaillon
4.2 2.4 t
.94 .8 .27 S % gold
0 0 1.5 C
1 1 1 S   % white
0 0 1.25 C
.94 .8 .27 S % gold
0 0 1 C

% Draw the ribbon
0 3 t
0 .31 .59 S   % blue
N 1.55 0 M
6 {60 rotate 1.55 0 L} repeat
F
1 1 1 S  % white
N
-.7 -1.35 M
-.05 0 L 
-.45 .9 L
.45 .9 L
-.5 -1.35 L
F

showpage
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: The ribbon and its sides are too short, the line connecting the spikes of the braces is lower than the medallion's outer ring, `& coding challenges` does not fit within the horizontal span of `CODE GOLF`, and the triangle and line are not aligned with the ribbon's corners.

Comment: Never mind, the triangle and line are good, but the line has an inconsistent thickness.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), <s>469</s> <s>477</s> 469 bytes

- +8 To fix the size of "CODE GOLF"
- -8 by talking tiny bit more liberty with the colours and removing  `on` after `hold` (given the default state of the `hold` is `off`, calling `hold` by itself just sets it to `on`)

```matlab
y=[1,.8,.3],b=[0,.4,.8],w=[1,1,1],hold
e='Edgecolor',n='none',r=@real,i=@imag,p=@patch,x=@text,f='FontSize'
h=1.8*exp(j*pi/3*(0:5))
p(r(h),i(h),b,e,n)
t=exp(pi*[3,-1,-5]/6j)+j
t=[t,.2*t(3),t(3)'-.3,t(3)']-.6j
p(r(t),i(t),w,e,n)
c=exp(pi*(0:98)/49j)
c=@(a,l)p(r(a*c-3.3j),i(a*c-3.3j),l,e,n)
c(1.5,y),c(1.3,w),c(1,y)
x(-4,-1,'{',f,99),x(2,-1,'}',f,99)
x(5,0,'CODE GOLF',f,49)
x(5,-3,'& coding challenges',f,31)
axis equal off,ylim([-5 2]),xlim([-4 25])
set(gcf,'Color',w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVHBjpswFLzzFZxqmz6cEMMq2ZUlpHa3l0p76BFx8DoGjBzMgtuQVv121k5SVZaeZ8bz5ll6VjrxS62NnU7CxXNnJ/cU35m0p1FIz6Wxs4qFMQEqMYVLPq0XXmVA90BZDW@82gLNPa3hHHR/auisOUaKo@djq6Q1dkIwcDTYQSGYeDkpYUDzUp9ECyMvR@FkBwsvnVocNBy92MH90L8Vijqe0X2ilhH3yag3LMHbx4KQaMQT7gjoUN5AwUAix4Nt1EnFIM0gLerNQ08@9/6hckB3icOMQCgopewG6pQ@9NcwF8J8Od/C5L8wP@@wJ5v80AexxAIMCX6RyJRR1oe2/9jcu3FGC7gQCIDB@Qo8jxac5uFz6A@CBg4HAgveXYW/d8FbCtgC@vL69Tn@9vr9Jej5XU8ZoE9@P0c9tLHs/GbU0Ko5WFhGIrHoOVbvP4WJbdPAxegTrtIi3tV@zo3k8a6oSTQrh1vZ@DG37ZzJuq4f), although you don't get the figure in TIO, so here is screenshot of the one I get.

[image: Screenshot]

Matlab version 9.3.0.948333 (R2017b) Update 9, on macOS Catalina, 10.15.4

### Ungolfed

```matlab
yellow = [246,204,70]/255;
blue = [0,97,186]/255;
white = [1 1 1];

hold on; % Allow multiple plots on the same axis (implicitly creates a figure)

% Make a blue hexagon
hex = exp(1i*2*pi/6*(0:5)); % Points on a hexagon
patch(real(1.8*hex),imag(1.8*hex),blue,'EdgeColor','none');

tri = exp(1i*(2*pi/3*(0:2)-3*pi/6))+1i;
tri = [tri (0.8*tri(1)+0.2*tri(3)) tri(3)'-0.3 tri(3)'];
patch(real(tri-.6i),imag(tri-.6i),white,'EdgeColor','none');

circ = exp(1i*linspace(0,2*pi,1e3)); % 100 points on a unit circle
co = -3.3i; % Offset
c = @(r,l)patch(real(r*circ+co),imag(r*circ+co),l,'EdgeColor','none');
c(1.5,yellow)
c(1.3,white)
c(1.0,yellow)

text(-4,-1,'{','FontSize',99);
text(2,-1,'}','FontSize',99);
text(5,-1.5,{'CODE GOLF','& coding challenges'},'FontSize',33)

axis equal off;
ylim([-5 2]); xlim([-4 25]);
set(gcf,'Color',white);
% grid on; box on;
```

Comment: Nice job! Just make sure "CODE GOLF" is large enough so that the "s" falls within the horizontal span of the "F".

Comment: @darrylyeo, Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed now. I had to add 8 bytes to to that, but I found an unrelated 8-byte saving on the way and so I broke even. :)

Comment: The triangle in the ribbon is not aligned with the corners of the ribbon.

Comment: Also, `& coding challenges` does not fit within the horizontal span of `CODE GOLF`.

Answer (score 2):

## LaTeX + TikZ, 449 bytes

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usetikzlibrary{shapes}\begin{document}\tikz{\path[fill]circle(1.6)(0,3)node[scale=32]{\{~\}}(0,5)node[fill,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,inner sep=70]{}(0,5)node[fill=white,rotate=180,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=20]{};\path[fill=white,rotate=60](0.6,1.5)rectangle(5,1.8)(0,0)circle(1.4);\fill circle(1)(17,3)node[scale=9,align=left]{CODE GOLF\\\tiny\&~coding challenges};}\enddocument
```

Readable version:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
\path[fill]
    circle(1.6)
    (0,3)node[scale=32]{\{~\}}
    (0,5)node[fill,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,inner sep=70]{}
    (0,5)node[fill=white,rotate=180,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=20]{};
    
\path[fill=white,rotate=60]
    (0.6,1.5)rectangle(5,1.8)
    (0,0)circle(1.4);
    
\fill
    circle(1)
    (17,3)node[scale=9,align=left]{CODE GOLF\\\tiny\&~coding challenges};
}
\enddocument
```

Outputs a PDF:

[image]

Comment: The height of that ribbon is nowhere *near* close to between \$3r\$ and \$4r\$.

Comment: Other problems: The outer ring is too thin and is not a perfect circle, the triangle and line aren't aligned with the corners of the ribbon, the ribbon's sides are too long, the braces are way too big, and `& coding challenges` does not fit within the horizontal span of `CODE GOLF`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 332 bytes

```
g=Graphics;r=GraphicsRow;c=RGBColor;r@{r@{Style["{",30],GraphicsColumn[{g@{c@"#0061BA",Polygon[{{15,6},{6,23},{15,40},{36,40},{43,23},{37,6},{17,6},{32,30},{19,30},{24,20}}]},g@{{c@"#F7CC46",Disk[]},{White,Thickness[.05],Circle[{0,0},.8]}}},ImageSize->Scaled[.04]],Style["}",30]},Column@{Style["CODEGOLF",15.5],"&codingChallenges"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9fS8MwFMW/SwSfriX9O6VM6jpXBGGyCj6UPoQspGFpI21FZshnr9fWDQK/3MPhnntaNjaiZaPibJrkuujZZ6P4kPbX78F8p3x9KDa50aZP@8ziK8ezFhWxBEJaw8WKjq@2q6zMLM/IDaWJv3ki8Gb0WRrUrR9D4sAmEIQInCKKDJOFUbjo4Wp2@QvCADP@xoeFQQQBda52gDFzzm6V51FCYKuGU4W6/WjUKOAdTzp1Yhgqj8Y15KrneLOlgFu8@9o5By8tk6JUP@LuseRMiyNao7qG/3purudg6XVtne@3z8X@dUfAjz3cTG65OapO5g3TWnRSDMS5afoF)

[image]

Comment: The outer radius is too small, the outer ring of the medallion is too thin, the line connecting the spikes of the braces is lower than the medallion's outer ring, the ribbon is too short and isn't horizontally symmetrical, the line extending out of the ribbon's triangle is too thin, the braces are too short, and `& coding challenges` does not fit within the horizontal span of `CODE GOLF`.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML + CSS, <s>958</s> <s>656</s> 588 bytes

[image]

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items:center; font-size:40px;">{

<div style="color: blue; line-height:0; transform: translate(-7px,07px); width: 32px">
  <div style="transform: scaleX(0.65); letter-spacing: -5px;">♦♦</div>
  <div style="width:16px; height:7px; background:blue; margin:-15px 0 0 15px "></div>
  <div style="transform: scale(0.47, 0.51); margin:14px 0 0 9px">▲</div>
  <div style="color: gold; font-size: 20px; margin:21px 0 0 13px">◉</div>
</div>

}<div><div style="font-size:21px">CODE GOLF</div><div style="font-size:14px">& coding challenges</div></div></div>
```

This solution works on Chrome and Safari

Comment: `& coding challenges` does not fit within the horizontal span of `CODE GOLF`, the outer radius in the medallion is too small, the outer ring is too thick, and the braces are too tall.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what version of Chrome/what OS you're using, but on Chrome on Windows, the ribbon is completely broken.